# Primordial perturbations, scale invariance and fundamental length

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation, cosmic-microwave-background

In cosmology, the initial perturbations to the metric can be described as $$\mathrm ds^2=-\mathrm dt^2+a(t)^2e^{2\zeta(\mathbf x)}\mathrm d^2x,\qquad(1)$$ where $\zeta(\mathbf x)$ is a gaussian random field with power spectrum $$\frac{k^3}{2\pi^2}P_\zeta(k)\propto k^{n_s-1}.\qquad(2)$$

A power spectrum in which $n_s=1$ (or the r.h.s. of (2) is constant) is associated with scale invariance. The fact that $n_s-1$ is positive (negative) means that shorter (larger) scales in Fourier space are *suppressed*, or that larger (shorter) scales in real space are *suppressed*.

Experimental data (PDG, 2020) shows that $n_s=0.965\pm0.004$, so $n_s-1$ is most likely negative, which would imply that the scale invariance breaks down as we *zoom in*, since the smaller scale structures are not there to resemble what one sees at a larger scale.

Is this, or could this be, related to the existence of a fundamental length scale?

Comment: The spectral index is determined by the causal mechanism that generates the perturbations, e.g. inflation or string gases.  The closest thing to the effect of a fundamental length scale I know of is in the context of inflation, where a short-distance cutoff on vacuum fluctuations is imposed which affects the spectrum; this is called the trans-Planckian problem.  It doesn't affect spectral index, but does cause modulations in the spectrum determined by the details of the inflationary epoch.